# Why, when determining the lengths of pendulums for a pendulum wave, do you use the equation $L = g[Tmax/2π(k+n+1)]^2$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, oscillators

Why, when determining the lengths of pendulums for a pendulum wave, do you use the equation $L = g[Tmax/2π(k+n+1)]^2$?

Comment: Welcome to [Physics.SE]!  If you can link to the video that would be helpful in answering your question.

Comment: That video explains nothing. What is $Tmax$ in your formula? What is $k$? What is $n$? Explain your formula at least.

Comment: *g is the force of gravity* No. it’s the *acceleration* due to gravity (at the Earth’s surface).

Comment: *n is the math pendulum* What is that supposed to mean?

Comment: Hi Lucien Jaccon. Welcome to Phys.SE. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Answer (score 2):

Let us analyse the video:

- There are $15$ pendulums.
- The cycle time is $T_\text{max}=60\text{ s}$
  (in the video from 0:26 to 1:26)
- Let us number the pendulums from longest ($n=1$) to shortest ($n=15$).
- During one cycle time the longest pendulum ($n=1$) does $51$ swings,
  the second longest pendulum ($n=2$) does $52$ swings,
  the third longest pendulum ($n=3$) does $53$ swings,
  ...
  and the shortest pendulum ($n=15$) does $65$ swings.
  Summarized: Pendulum $n$ does $50+n$ swings per cycle time.

Using $T_\text{max} = 60$ s, defining $k=49$ and calling the pendulum period $T$, we can write the number of swings per cycle time as:
$$\frac{T_\text{max}}{T} = k+n+1 \tag{1}$$

So the pendulum period $T$ is :
$$T = \frac{T_\text{max}}{k+n+1} \tag{2}$$

On the other hand we know the [period of a pendulum with length $L$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_(mechanics)#Rule_of_thumb_for_pendulum_length) is
$$T=2\pi\sqrt{\frac{L}{g}} \tag{3}$$

Equating (2) and (3) we get
$$2\pi\sqrt{\frac{L}{g}} = \frac{T_\text{max}}{k+n+1} \tag{4}$$

Resolving this for pendulum length $L$ we get:
$$L = g\left[\frac{T_\text{max}}{2\pi(k+n+1)}\right]^2  \tag{5}$$

Answer (score -1):

You find the answer in wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_wave

Comment: [Are link-only answers acceptable?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/859/are-link-only-answers-acceptable) (No.)

Comment: Thanks, I will not do it again.